# How to convert Numeric Character Reference to Unicode in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode

For example, `&#20B9` should be converted to `₹` . There is a way to do this in Python, Javascript and some other languages.

Is there any library that could help me with this conversion?

Note : I am parsing a string that contains a numeric character reference

Comment: In what context? Are you parsing a string? A file? There is nowhere near enough information in this question to make it answerable.

Comment: Yes, there is library, see http://site.icu-project.org/

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
std::string s = "&#20B9";
char32_t ch = std::stoi(s.substr(2), nullptr, 16);
```

If you want UTF-8 then there are ways to do it in "pure" C++, but it's easier to use libraries such as [the ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/).